# magento 2.1 change address structure hierarchy

Tags: magento-2.1, address

I want to show `state`, `province`, `postcode` in line like below
india-dehli 185235 
how can i change the hierarchy of `address` structure?

Comment: where? in customer panel? registration page? where do you want change?

Comment: In customer panel i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override below file:

> Magento_Root/vendor/hamechio/theme-frontend-pg/Magento_Sales/templates/order/items/renderer/default.phtml